# How to insert in same table sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `AccessRight` with this sample data:

```
ID   Accessfor   AccessOn
---------------------------
 1     40            51
 2     40            52
 3     40            53
 4     43            51
 4     43            54
 5     43            55
```

I want to insert/delete records of accessfor=40 and insert this table as a accessfor=43 
means table will have records like below

```
1     43            51
2     43            52
3     43            53
4     43            54
5     43            55
```

Please suggest best optimum approach to solved this.

Comment: cant you make update to Accessfor = 40 to Accessfor  = 43

Answer (score 1):

use `update` and `delete`

Use `CTE` to delete the duplicate records after updation.

```
update table set Accessfor = 43 where Accessfor = 40

;with cte as
(
select row_number() over (partition by Accessfor, AccessOn order by id) rn,* 
from table
)
delete from cte where rn>1
```

Comment: Thank you.But doing above query is giving error like below.Please do the needful 'AK_UserGroupRelation_GroupIDUserID'. The duplicate key value is (43, 51)

Comment: There seem to be constraint on table. First drop the constraint in start of query and add constraint again after delete

Comment: DBA will not allow to drop constrains,Please do the need ful.

Comment: @SandipkTatva - what is the problem in dropping and  recreating

Answer (score 1):

```
 Insert into AccessRight(ID,AccessFor,AccessOn)
   (select id,43,AccessOn from AccessRight where accessfor = 40 
   and accessOn not in(select accessOn from AccessRight where accessfor = 43));
   Delete from AccessRight where accessfor = 40;
```

**EDIT :** (Try this)

```
Insert into AccessRight(ID,AccessFor,AccessOn)
(
select id,0,AccessOn from AccessRight 
where id+''+accessfor+''+accesson not in (
select id+''+accessfor+''+accesson from accessright
where accessfor = 43
and accesson in(select accesson from accessright where accessfor = 40)
)
);
delete from accessright where accessfor <> 0;
update accessright set accessfor = 43;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use update query to solve your problem like

```
update yourtablename set Accessfor=43 where Accessfor=40
```

i hope this may help you

Comment: Then what about the duplicate entries like 43 51 and 43 51?Please advise priya786

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is take distinct AccessOn record to temp table and truncate first table and re insert all the distinct records with Accessfor = 43.

Check this :

```
-- Your Main Table
Create table #temp1
(
   Accessfor int,
   AccessOn int
)

-- This will be temp table
Create table #temp2
(
   Accessfor int,
   AccessOn int
)

-- Insert into Main table. This step was for me to get data in Main table.
Insert into #temp1 values(40, 51)
Insert into #temp1 values(40, 52)
Insert into #temp1 values(40, 53)
Insert into #temp1 values(43, 51)
Insert into #temp1 values(43, 54)
Insert into #temp1 values(43, 55)

select * from #temp1

--From here actual operation starts...
Insert into #temp2
  Select Distinct '43', AccessOn From #temp1

Truncate table #temp1
Insert into #temp1
  Select * From #temp2

select * from #temp1
```

Answer (score 0):

then you can check it with the query

```
mysql_query("select id from tablename where  Accessfor=43 &&  Accesson='anyvalue'");
if(mysql_num_rows()>0)
{
mysql_query("delete from tablename Accessfor=43 &&  Accesson='anyvalue'");
}
else
{
//you do update
}
```